# Airmon -ng issue , kali linux

Tags: windows-10, kali-linux

I installed kali linux lite on my windows 10. 
When I cmd
 "Airmon -ng"  it shows as 
"ls: cannot access '/sys/class/ieee80211/': No such file or directory .

What should I so please help. I've been trying to fix it by following many posts but no use.

Answer (score 0):

> I installed kali linux lite on my windows 10

WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) does not provide a full Linux kernel, only an emulation layer on top of the existing Windows kernel. This emulation doesn't include – and probably won't include – low-level interfaces like mac80211, due to their complexity and architectural differences between the two OSes. (Either many things wouldn't work, or they would conflict with Windows' *own* wireless network management.)

You will need to run Kali on bare metal.